# Splitting lines in python based on some character

Tags: python

Input:

```
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:12,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/1
2/19,19:34:13,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:14,000.
0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:15,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W
55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:16,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56
281,12/12/19,19:34:17,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34
:18,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:19,000.0,0,37N22.
```

Output:

```
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:12,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:13,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:14,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:15,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:16,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:17,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:18,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:19,000.0,0,37N22.
```

'!' is the starting character and +0013 should be the ending of each line (if present).

Problem which I am getting:
Output is like :

```
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:12,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/1
2/19,19:34:13,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:14,000.
0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:15,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W
```

Any help would be highly appreciated...!!!

My code:

```
file_open= open('sample.txt','r') 
file_read= file_open.read() 
file_open2= open('output.txt','w+') 
counter =0 
for i in file_read: 
    if '!' in i: 
        if counter == 1: 
            file_open2.write('\n') 
            counter= counter -1 
        counter= counter +1 
    file_open2.write(i)
```

Comment: My Code: My code:


    file_open= open('sample.txt','r')
    file_read= file_open.read()    
    file_open2= open('output.txt','w+')
    counter =0
        
    for i in file_read:
        if '!' in i:
            if counter == 1:
                file_open2.write('\n')
                counter= counter -1 
            counter= counter +1
        file_open2.write(i)

Comment: I've added your code in to your question, but I'm not sure if the indentation is correct. Feel free to fix it, and next time edit your question directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
with open("abc.txt") as f:
    data=f.read().replace("\r\n","")  #replace the newlines with ""

    #the newline can be "\n" in your system instead of "\r\n"

    ans=filter(None,data.split("!"))  #split the data at '!', then filter out empty lines
    for x in ans:
        print "!"+x    #or write to some other file
   .....:         
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:12,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:13,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:14,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:15,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:16,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:17,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:18,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:19,000.0,0,37N22.
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use `str.split`?

```
lines = file_read.split('!')
```

Now lines is a list which holds the split data.  This is almost the lines you want to write -- The only difference is that they don't have trailing newlines and they don't have `'!'` at the start.  We can put those in easily with string formatting -- e.g. `'!{0}\n'.format(line)`.  Then we can put that whole thing in a generator expression which we'll pass to `file.writelines` to put the data in a new file:

```
file_open2.writelines('!{0}\n'.format(line) for line in lines)
```

You might need:

```
file_open2.writelines('!{0}\n'.format(line.replace('\n','')) for line in lines)
```

if you find that you're getting more newlines than you wanted in the output.

A few other points, when opening files, it's nice to use a context manager -- This makes sure that the file is closed properly:

```
with open('inputfile') as fin:
    lines = fin.read()
with open('outputfile','w') as fout:
    fout.writelines('!{0}\n'.format(line.replace('\n','')) for line in lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using `replace` instead of split, since you know the starting and ending characters of each line:

```
In [14]: data = """!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:12,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/1
2/19,19:34:13,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:14,000.
0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:15,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W
55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:16,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56
281,12/12/19,19:34:17,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34
:18,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:19,000.0,0,37N22.""".replace('\n', '')

In [15]: print data.replace('+0013!', "+0013\n!")
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:12,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:13,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:14,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:15,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:16,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:17,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:18,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
!,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:19,000.0,0,37N22.
```

Comment: Thanks acjohnson, but i guess this will not be effective in case of large files.

Comment: True.  You'll probably want to use a block-based strategy for that, but I don't think there's anything about using replace that's necessarily worse than regex or split options, form this standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Just for some variance, here is a regular expression answer:

```
import re

outputFile = open('output.txt', 'w+') 
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f: 
    for line in re.findall("!.+?(?=!|$)", f.read(), re.DOTALL): 
        outputFile.write(line.replace("\n", "") + '\n') 

outputFile.close()
```

It will open the output file, get the contents of the input file, and loop through all the matches using the regular expression `!.+?(?=!|$)` with the [re.DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag. The regular expression explanation & what it matches can be found here: http://regex101.com/r/aK6aV4

After we have a match, we strip out the new lines from the match, and write it to the file.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Your solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to add a `\n` before every "!"; then let python [splitlines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) :-)  :

```
file_read.replace("!", "!\n").splitlines()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this solution does not give desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I will actually implement as a generator so that you can work on the data stream rather than the entire content of the file. This will be quite memory friendly if working with huge files

```
>>> def split_on_stream(it,sep="!"):
    prev = ""
    for line in it:
        line = (prev + line.strip()).split(sep)
        for parts in line[:-1]:
            yield parts
        prev = line[-1]
    yield prev


>>> with open("test.txt") as fin:
    for parts in split_on_stream(fin):
        print parts



,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:12,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:13,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:14,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:15,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:16,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:17,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:18,000.0,0,37N22.714,121W55.576,+0013
,A,56281,12/12/19,19:34:19,000.0,0,37N22.
```